# function argument declare in other place?

Tags: javascript

```
function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
            )
```

I am new to javascript and i happened to see these lines of codes.
I would like to know if the code moves the function argument to the later part of the code?
That means it is the same as following.

```
function preload("http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg") {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
```

Because I see no reference on w3cschool so I post this question.
Hope it is not too stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second code snippet you've provided, the preload method is being declared, meaning you cannot pass it data as arguments, you can only declare those arguments` names. The first snippet, you've posted consists of two parts.  A function declaration and a call to that function, with three URLs as parameters.

Notice that in the function declaration, no parameters are actually define. It's as if the function shouldn't accept any. This is because, the creator of said function decided that the amount of parameters this function should receive is variable.

To do this, he uses the `arguments` array, which every JavaScript function has within it's scope. It's an array-like object, which contains every argument passed to the function.

Comment: can i directly edit the arguments array then call the function with new arguments array with desired inputs?

Comment: the next answer just answered my question here

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand how parameters work.  Take a look at the following examples:

```
function func1(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    console.log(arg1);
    console.log(arg2);
    console.log(arg3);
}

function func2() {
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

These two functions are equivalent for three parameters:

```
func1('test1', 'test2', 'test3');            // Output:  test1, test2, test3
func2('test1', 'test2', 'test3');            // Output:  test1, test2, test3
```

However only the 2nd will print out all four parameters while the first will only print out the three:

```
func2('test1', 'test2', 'test3');             // Output:  test1, test2, test3
func2('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4');    // Output:  test1, test2, test3, test4
```

In your 2nd example, you're confusing parameters and their values.  A function's *parameters* should always be variables because they could hold very well any value (not only strings!).  Your function declaration should therefore perform the action on the variable holding the value and when calling the function, you can pass both variables with values or string values directly (as in the case of the first example).

Hope that helps!